# Set Scale Button Doesn't Work

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, scale, python-addin

I'm trying to create a button that sets the map scale to 24000. I'm working in ArcMap 10.1 and my Python programming skill is rudimentary.

I followed the Python Add-In instructions and the creation was successful - I have a new toolbar and a new button - but nothing happens when I click the button. Here's the code:

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class ButtonClass13(object):
    """Implementation for ScaleBtn_addin.Scale24 (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        df.scale = 24000
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 1):

The sharp eyes of a coworker showed me that the scale had changed and was showing as 1:24,000. Refreshing the map then displayed it at the new scale.

Adding `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()` at the end of the code took care of the problem.